# update multiple columns same time

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to update a table with multiple columns in same query( and also with if else clause) can any guide me to get the desired output.

```
update tablename 
set 
  IsEmailable=CASE 
    WHEN Email IS NOT NULL AND DNIInd <> 'Y' AND DoNotEmail <> 'Y' THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
  END,
  IsCallable=CASE 
    WHEN (ResTlphnNum IS NOT NULL OR CellTlphnNum IS NOT NULL) AND DoNotCallInd <> 'Y' AND DNIInd <> 'Y' THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
  END,
  IsMailable=CASE 
    WHEN AddrLine1Txt IS NOT NULL AND BadAddrInd <> 'Y' AND DoNotMailInd <> 'Y' AND DNIInd <> 'Y' THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
  END;
```

Comment: This Update is valid syntax.

Comment: Add some examples of the rows you expect to be getting updated; since this is now valid sql, the issue must be with the logic used to determine how they should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a case statement:

```
update tablename set IsEmailable=CASE WHEN Email IS NOT NULL AND DNIInd='N' AND DoNotEmail='N' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, 

IsCallable=CASE WHEN (ResTlphnNum IS NOT NULL OR CellTlphnNum IS NOT NULL) AND DoNotCallInd='N' AND DNIInd='N' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,

IsMailable=CASE WHEN AddrLine1Txt IS NOT NULL AND BadAddrInd='N' AND DoNotMailInd='N' AND DNIInd='N' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work, how do we update multiple columns , I mean like set IsCallable=CASE AND IsMailable=CASE

Comment: @dani you should probably be more specific than "did not work"; this answer should do exactly what you want.

Comment: The comma between the columns should allow multiple column updates.  What error are you getting?
update table set field1=value1, field2=value2.  Looking at your comment, you are trying to use AND.  Don't do this.  Just look at my example query as-is.  There is a comma between each field to be updated.

Comment: @Uueerdo I mean I was using this query update  tablename set IsEmailable=CASE WHEN Email IS NOT NULL AND DNIInd='N' AND DoNotEmail='N' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, 
IsCallable=CASE WHEN (ResTlphnNum IS NOT NULL OR CellTlphnNum IS NOT NULL) AND DoNotCallInd='N' AND DNIInd='N' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
IsMailable=CASE WHEN AddrLine1Txt IS NOT NULL AND BadAddrInd='N' AND DoNotMailInd='N' AND DNIInd='N' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END; Do I need to set for IsCallable=CASE AND IsMailable=CASE as well in the query ??

Comment: query looks good.  are you getting an error?  does the case statement work if you just try to update one field?  this should work on sql server or oracle--are you using some other dbms?

Comment: @PaulX   I'm using Terdata

Comment: @dani you only need one `SET` in an update query; the basic format is UPDATE _sometable_ SET _fieldA_ = _something_, _fieldB_ = _somethingelse_, _and so on...._ WHERE _somecondition_ (at least for MySQL, that is the format)

Comment: @Uueerdo Not sure what is the issue here, fyi I'm using teradata if that has something to do with that

Comment: i have to be done here.  you are not saying what the issue is.  is it erroring, or is it not updating, or something else?  you need to provide more info or example outputs.

Comment: @PaulX I guess query is not getting executed and the table is not getting update